# How to remove less than hundred fraction of a decimal

Tags: c#, sql, .net, math, decimal

I want to remove any fractions less than hundred of a decimal. For example if its 7526.50 then I want it to be 7500 (26.50 deducted). In C# I'm doing this as follows.

```
NetWage = decimal.Truncate(netEarning / 100) * 100;
```

How to do this in Sql (MS SQL Server) ?

Is there a more elegant way to do this in C#?

Comment: You just need to round to the nearest 100?

Comment: @hometoast He needs to *truncate* (not round) to the nearest 100, hence the use of the `Truncate` method.

Comment: Modulus is the way to go here.  Use the % operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a more elegant way to do this in C#?

Am not sure this is elegant, but there is a way(which I use).

```
decimal d =7526.50m;
decimal truncated = d - (d % 100);
```

You can apply the same logic in SQL too.

Answer (score 1):

In C#:

```
Math.Round(7526.50m / 100m, 0) * 100m
```

In SQL Server:

```
SELECT ROUND((7526.50 / 100), 0) * 100
```

If you need Integer values, rather than decimal values, use this instead:

In C#:

```
(int) (Math.Round(7526.50m / 100m, 0) * 100m)
```

In SQL Server:

```
SELECT CAST( ROUND((7526.50 / 100), 0) * 100 AS INT)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following in T-SQL.

```
select floor(cast(7526.50/100 as int))*100 as mynum
```